# How to print out ttk.Combobox options in multiple frames?

Tags: python, tkinter

In my code, there are two frames. In the first one, I put in an <kbd>Add</kbd> button that will produce a new frame with a `Combobox`. The idea is to add a few `Combobox` like that in the first frame, pick different options for different `Combobox`, and then print them out in the next frame. But when I hit the `Show options` button in the second frame, it doesn't print out the options that I just chose in the first frame. How can I solve this?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

list_1 = []


class Validation_Tool(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("PageOne")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def quit(self):
        self.destroy()


class PageOne(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        def add_compare():
            global list_1

            frame = Frame(self)
            frame.pack()

            label_1 = Label(frame, text='Options')
            label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

            self.options_1 = ttk.Combobox(frame, values=['a','b','c','d','e'])
            self.options_1.grid(row=1, column=0)

            list_1.append(self.options_1.get())

        quit_button = Button(self, text="Quit Program",
                    command=lambda: controller.quit())
        next_button = Button(self, text="Next",
                    command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        add_button = Button(self, text='Add', command=add_compare)

        quit_button.place(relx=0.98, rely=0.98, anchor=SE)
        next_button.place(relx=0.76, rely=0.98, anchor=SE)
        add_button.place(relx=0.661, rely=0.98, anchor=SE)


class PageTwo(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        def button():
            label = Label(self, text=list_1)
            label.pack()

        quit_button = Button(self, text="Quit Program",
                            command=lambda: controller.quit())
        back_button = Button(self, text="Back",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        show_button = Button(self, text='Show options', command=button)
        show_button.pack()

        back_button.place(relx=0.76, rely=0.98, anchor=SE)
        quit_button.place(relx=0.98, rely=0.98, anchor=SE)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Validation_Tool()
    root.geometry('400x300+430+250')
    root.title("Validation Tool")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read about [scopes-and-namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example) and [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your code that will print the options selected so far when the <kbd>Next</kbd> is pressed. To prevent the `Combobox`es from interferring with each other a list of them and an associated `StringVar`s is kept.

Having separate `StringVar`s avoids the problem of choosing an option on one of them from changing it on the others — i.e. a different `textvar` gets associated with each one.

To make collecting all the options together into `list_1`, a callback function named `selected()` has been defined and gets "bound" to `Combobox` selection events. This make it so that, in addition to the above, the option selected will also get appended to the global `list_1`, which is what the <kbd>Show options</kbd> button displays.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

list_1 = []


class Validation_Tool(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.comboboxes = []  # Comboboxes created. ADDED
        self.combobox_vars = []  # Vars for Comboboxes. ADDED.

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("PageOne")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def quit(self):
        self.destroy()

class PageOne(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        # Combobox event handler. ADDED
        def selected(event, var):
            list_1.append(var.get())  # Append Combobox option selected.

        def add_compare():
            frame = Frame(self)
            frame.pack()

            label_1 = Label(frame, text='Options')
            label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

            combobox_var = StringVar()  # ADDED.
            combobox = ttk.Combobox(frame, values=list('abcde'),
                                    textvar=combobox_var)  # For each Combobox. ADDED.
            combobox.grid(row=1, column=0)
            combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',  # Bind event handler.           ADDED.
                          lambda event, var=combobox_var: selected(event, var))  # ADDED.

            self.controller.comboboxes.append(combobox)         # ADDED.
            self.controller.combobox_vars.append(combobox_var)  # ADDED.

        quit_button = Button(self, text="Quit Program",
                             command=lambda: controller.quit())
        next_button = Button(self, text="Next",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        add_button = Button(self, text='Add',
                            command=add_compare)

        quit_button.place(relx=0.98, rely=0.98, anchor=SE)
        next_button.place(relx=0.76, rely=0.98, anchor=SE)
        add_button.place(relx=0.661, rely=0.98, anchor=SE)


class PageTwo(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        def button():
            label = Label(self, text=list_1)
            label.pack()

        quit_button = Button(self, text="Quit Program",
                            command=lambda: controller.quit())
        back_button = Button(self, text="Back",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        show_button = Button(self, text='Show options', command=button)
        show_button.pack()

        back_button.place(relx=0.76, rely=0.98, anchor=SE)
        quit_button.place(relx=0.98, rely=0.98, anchor=SE)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Validation_Tool()
    root.geometry('400x300+430+250')
    root.title("Validation Tool")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I have more than one `Combobox` in the first page, I pick one option in one `Combobox` and suddenly every other `Combobox` get the same option. For example, I have three `Combobox`, I pick 'a' in the first `Combobox`, then the other two will automatically set to 'a'. I want to be able to choose different options for different `Combobox`.

Comment: @Chris: The code in your question has only one `Combobox`, so you're effectively asking a different question. Please update the current one accordingly or ask a new question.

Comment: @Chris: You need to also update the code in the question accordingly.

Comment: There is an `Add` button in my first page. A new `Combobox` will be added to the frame when that button is clicked.

Comment: @Chris: I know that. The code in my answer collects the options selected in _all_ of them and displays all of them when the 'Show options` button is clicked — so I think it already addresses having more than one.

Comment: Yes, but as I have stated above, when I choose an option in one `Combobox`, the other `Combobox` automatically change to the same option. If I have three `Combobox` and I choose 'a' for one of them, I got three 'a'. I can't choose different options for different `Combobox`.

Comment: @Chris: Oh, OK — sorry — I'll look into that.